# Unrecognized option "--enable-new-dtags" error during building c++ library

Tags: cmake, mingw, msys

During building a c++ source code (configured with cmake gui) with mingw under MSYS gives following error while trying to "Linking C shared library":

```
Unrecognized option "--enable-new-dtags"
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Likely --enable-new-dtags is supported only on ELF targets. For example there's a patch for Python3 distutils which sets this flag conditionally on the target platform: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-python3/0260-MINGW-compiler-enable-new-dtags.patch . You should make sure that this flag isn't specified explicitly somewhere in your project.